# Code signing problems while testing on device

Tags: xcode, distribution, app-store-connect, code-signing

I am preparing my app to go to send it to iTunesConnect, then I created a provisioning profile for my app distribution. When I go test my app on device with the Distribution configuration the app doesn't open and an message appears `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.` My Question is: Is there a problem to test on device an app with Distribution code signing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile to testing a release build. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1

Or use a service. I use [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) to distribute betas and love it I also use [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com/) for crash reporting and will be including crashlytics in my App Store release but not the TestFlight SDK.